# Eloquent model updating more rows that it should laravel php

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a table without primary key that looks like this:

| user_id | config_key | config_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2296 | config_key_1 | config_value_1 |
| 2296 | config_key_2 | config_value_2 |
| 2296 | config_key_3 | config_value_3 |
| 2296 | config_key_4 | config_value_4 |

And every time I try to update one value from that table, for some reason the rest of the table is updated with the same values, like this:

| user_id | config_key | config_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2296 | config_key_1 | config_value_1 |
| 2296 | config_key_2 | config_value_1 |
| 2296 | config_key_3 | config_value_1 |
| 2296 | config_key_4 | config_value_1 |

My query looks like this:

```
$ConfigValue = AppUserConfig::where('user_id', 2296)
                ->where('config_key', 'config_key_1')
                ->first();
```

```
$ConfigValue->config_value = config_value_1;
$ConfigValue->save();
```

I just basically need to update one row of my table, from this:

| user_id | config_key | config_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2296 | config_key_1 | config_value_1 |
| 2296 | config_key_2 | config_value_2 |
| 2296 | config_key_3 | config_value_3 |
| 2296 | config_key_4 | config_value_4 |

To this:

| user_id | config_key | config_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2296 | config_key_1 | new_custom_value |
| 2296 | config_key_2 | config_value_2 |
| 2296 | config_key_3 | config_value_3 |
| 2296 | config_key_4 | config_value_4 |

But not sure, what is happening :(

Both solutions pretty much solved it, thanks, everyone.

Comment: Would you mind posting a bit more of the actual PHP code so we can understand in what context you are performing this query?

Comment: `$ConfigValue->config_value = config_value_1;` <- Is that a typo? `config_value_1` without `'` or `"` would likely trigger an error of some kind (unless you've defined it as a constant, etc.)

Comment: Since you don't have a primary key, you'd probably have to actually do this with Query Builder instead of using Eloquent, or use Eloquent with the Query Builder. But you won't be able to pull out a single record as an object to update it.

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/29984

Comment: Also, the `save()` method would probably fail here because it is looking to update the row at a specific primary id in the table.

Comment: why not make it `one to many` relationship. I can't follow what are you doing in this scenario. Instead of making the primary key complicated, you can do like:`User->AppConfig` so it's easy to read  and maintain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing weird going on, when you update a record using Eloquent, your update statement would use the primary key to identify that record, we can just assume that it tries to update all rows with id `2296`. you can use debug tools like `clockwork` or `telescope` to verify the actual SQL statement queries when you run your code

You can also try using Query builder for update statement
e.i.

```
DB::table('app_user_config_whatever')
    ->where('user_id', 2296)
    ->where('config_key', 'config_key_1')
    ->update(['config_value' => 'config_value_1']);
```

but the best approach would be to create a proper relationship between user and config, like having the config `belognsTo` a user, then you can perform something like

```
$user->config()
    ->where('config_key', 'config_key_1')
    ->update(['config_value' => 'config_value_1']);
```

or

```
$user->config()
    ->updateOrCreate( 
        ['config_key' => 'config_key_1' ], 
        ['config_key' => 'config_key_1', 'config_value' => 'config_value_1'] 
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

you can update by using update query like this

```
$ConfigValue = AppUserConfig::where('user_id', 2296)
                ->where('config_key', 'config_key_1')
                ->update(['config_value'=>'config_value_1']);
```